# change color of hyperlinks on exporting Libreoffice writer to PDF

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, pdf

I use `Ubuntu 22.04` and `LibreOffice Writer 7.3.5.2`. I changed the color of hyper links by going to `tools -> options -> LibreOffice -> application colors` and changing/enabling `Unvisited links` and `Visited links`. But when I export as PDF, color of hyperlinks has not changed (remained blue as were). How can I change the color of hyperlinks on exporting as PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to control the appearance of hyperlinks in Writer is to avoid direct formatting (selecting the text and changing the format) and instead modify the built-in character style "Internet Link". Links in Writer use the settings from those styles, and the formatting will export to pdf as well.

This is achieved from within Writer as follows:

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> to open Styles and select the icon for Character Styles (a large A). From there, navigate down to "Internet Link" (which is underscored) right click and select Modify then select the Font Effects tab and change the font colour as required remembering to select Apply thereafter to save your changes.

[image]

[image]

You can read about Styles in the [Writer Guide](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/en/english-documentation/) and how to use character styles instead of direct formatting.